# Why does this jQuery list toggle code not work?

Tags: jquery

I totally wonder why this code doesn't work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol ol').hide();

  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ol').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
```

If you click for example "Coffee", then the subordinate list should fold out. Is there a little mistake? Unfortunately, I can't find it.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. The sub `<ol>` elements should be within `<li>`. See the _"Permitted content"_ section here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#properties

Comment: Apart malformed html of ol , the function only takes one tag as argument (there is no such tag as "ol ol"  , you can use  Id #mylist1 name per invocation. Repeat the call code per set with each ol tag and unique Id .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `ol` inside `li`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol ol').hide();

  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ol').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>
    Coffee
    <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Tea
   <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ol`s aren't children of the `li` you're clicking on - you need to change the markup to:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Tea  
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `ol` is not the children of `li`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol ol').hide();

  $('li').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ol').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Tea
    <ol>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
```

Or you can change your js, use `next('ol')` to select `ol` behind the `li` you click.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
</ol>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ol ol').hide();
    $('li').click(function() {
      $(this).next('ol').toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ol ol').hide();
  $('li').click(function() {
    $('ol ol').hide();
    $(this).children('ol').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>
    Coffee
    <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Tea
   <ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
</ol>
```

Try this code to open a at time one li ol.